# How to create free in-app-purchase?

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, storekit

I need one of my in-app purchases to be free, possibly with the provided by Apple IAP structure?

Currently the type of that purchase is `non-consumable` while it's payed everything is okay, but the problem is that if i made it 'free" from price tiers, i receive it's ID in `invalidProductIdentifiers`.

Comment: here is the complete guide for in-app purchase have a look at that...
http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NOTE** This was accurate when it was written, but has since become outdated

You cannot have a free In App Purchase.  Think about it.  What would Apple gain by giving you free hosting for your stuff?  If you charge for it they get 30% and that makes them happy but 30% of nothing is nothing.  You will need to host the content yourself.

Source:  My experience with IAP

Comment: The point here is that i don't have hosting from them, I only have to unlock feature which is free, but now required from all users.

Comment: What is the point of it then?  If it's free then why does the user need to "purchase" it at all?

Comment: @borrrden for example allow user to unlock it for free using promo code :). If you use apples IAP system user can restore the purchase everywhere

Comment: I intend to create non renewal subscription. I want to sell for free and then after a few months, I would like to sell it for specific amount. So is it possible ? I saw an option "Free" while selecting price tier in iTunesconnect.

Comment: The Free price tier is now available in iTunes Connect.

Comment: @h4cky You should consider unaccepting my answer since it has become outdated.

Answer (score 8):

Apple have now added a Free price tier for in app purchases. I've tested it with a non-consumable for an app that is currently in the store and it works perfectly.

Just go to 'Manage In-App Purchases' in iTunes Connect, select the product and change the price tier to Free. Then, when you fetch the SKProduct in your app the price will be 0.

Comment: I've tested this and those product with price of 0, didn't appear as valid products I will check them again.

Comment: curious to know the result! anyone have an official reference to this?

Comment: we don't see the free tier. did you do something to enable the free tier?

Comment: @Crashalot Not that I'm aware of. It just appears as one of the available tiers for in app purchases.

Comment: Can I do the same for non renewing subscription ? I want to sell a product for free and after some time want to make them paid.

Answer (score 2):

In-app purchases are for products which can be purchased, or has minimum Tier1 pricing, else it cannot be consider into inapp process.

You app should have list of products which are available for in-app, else other should be skipped from the in-app process.

Comment: @h4cky It is not mentioned any where in the docs, but when you do so, your app will not recognize the product identifier, I have experienced it. So it is assumed that in-app needs to process a payment, and transaction which is not possible in case of Free products..

Answer (score 2):

This is possible for non-consumable IAPs:

[image: img]