# Change iOS in-app-purchase price to free? How to reproduce what an app has done?

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, itunes, app-store-connect

iTunes Connect doesn't seem to offer a free tier for in-app-purchases. So how does this app get all IAP prices to free?

Other SO posts talk about changing the price, but none address changing the price to free like this app did.

app in question (no affiliation): https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/quick-4-minute-workout-tabata/id803491681?mt=8

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create free in-app-purchase?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144444/how-to-create-free-in-app-purchase)

Comment: @Raptor this isn't a duplicate. that question is outdated and doesn't address the question posed: how to reproduce what the app did in making the IAPs free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this is possible for non-consumable IAPs. As below, someone was able to set the Price Tier to Free:

[image: Price Schedule — Price Tier: Free]

Answer (score 2):

Some IAPs may become free while others may not, as Crashalot introduced.
So here you have a table of what in-app purchases may become free and which ones may not[image: Table with in-app purchases that may become free and in-apps that may not].